# ScrollViewer styled with images doesn't scroll on full track

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, scrollbar, scrollviewer

In my WPF application, I have styled the ScrollBar using images for the background and the thumb. The scrollbar is scrolling along the whole height of the scrollbar. But inside ScrollViewer, the thumb doesn't scroll along the whole track. It scrolls in the middle of the track but doesn't get close to the ends of the scrollbars. Please see the attached image.

Below is the ScrollBar style:

```
    <ImageBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Background" ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/ZeePad v1.65B for dev Vertical Slide.png" Stretch="Fill" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Horizontal.Background" ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/ZeePad v1.65B for dev Vertical Slide - Horizontal.png" Stretch="Fill" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb" ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/ZeePad v1.65B for dev Slider Knob.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb" ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/ZeePad v1.65B for dev Slider Knob.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
<ImageBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Thumb" ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/ZeePad v1.65B for dev Slider Knob.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Border" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbVertical" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Thumb}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Thumb}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" >
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbVertical}"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Horizontal.Background}" />
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHorizontal}"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The ScrollView style is as given below:

```
    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: Image Attached]

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: Show some code, will help your troubleshooting.

Comment: Sure Chris W., I will update the question with code.

Comment: Can some one please answer my question? Thanks.